# Присвоение значения переменной при объявлении в классе

Tags: c++, классы, инициализация

Есть класс:

```
class A
{
  public: 
      static int count;

      A()
      {
          count++; // При создании каждого объекта эта переменная должна увеличиваться
      }
};
```

Надо присвоить значение этой переменной 0, до вызова конструктора. Но если это сделать вот так:

```
static int count = 0;
```

То компилятор ругается. Как обойтись в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто надо правильно определить эту переменную **вне класса**

```
class A
{
  public: 
      static int count;

      A()
      {
          count++; // При создании каждого объекта эта переменная должна увеличиваться
      }
};

//...
int A::count = 0;
```

Вы также можете опустить инициализатор, так как переменная в любом случае будет инициализирована нулем:

```
int A::count;
```

Если определение класса помещено в заголовочный файл, то определение статической переменной нужно поместить в один из программных модулей.